CMD executes powershell command to continuously log (tail) a file but does not return back to cmd or execute next command
I am using CMD to execute PowerShell command for logging (tailing a data file "trun.out" that updates from a simulation run). > See the "Call start Poweshell" portion of the code below.
if %therm%==y (del /f trun.out
    fsutil file createnew trun.out 8192
    CALL start powershell -noninteractive -File "trun_tail_powershell.ps1"
    if %dist_solve%==1 (%ans_path% -b -dis -np %num_proc% -j %job% -run %run% -i therm.inp -o trun.out) else (%ans_path% -b -dis -np %num_proc% -f -m 30000 -db 5000 -j $job -run %run% -i therm.inp -o trun.out)   
    REM END 
    )
dir 

After the if statement is executed, a new powershell window opens (it is done purposefully so that the data logging can be seen separately). Logs the trun.out data file.
However, CMD does not execute "dir" command right after the if statement.
I first thought that CMD opening a new powershell window for data logging does not returns the authority (not sure if this is the correct word to use) back to CMD to move on to the next command, so I tried commenting the data logging section and not creating any powershell window. But I am still having the issue. It does not execute anything after the if statement.
But if I place the "dir" command inside if statement, it will show the directory.
Would appreciate any help/guidance as I am quite new using CMD and powershell altogatehr.

Before you do anything else, remove CALL. It should not be there. Then when you update your question to include the new code and observations, ensure that what you submit can be run by us. That means we want a [mcve]. We have no idea what the values of %therm%, %dist_solve%, %job%, %ans_path%, %num_proc%, and %run% are, or how they were defined in that cmd.exe instance.

If any of those variables are defined or redfined within the powershell.exe instance, those are currently isolated only within PowerShell, and not propagated to the initial cmd.exe instance.

Why involve cmd at all? Just write it all in PowerShell.

@Compo, all of these are variables, to run a simulation in ansys.
%therm% refers to a flag with Y or N to enter seperate conditions in my if-else statement
%num_proc% defines the number of processor to be used.
The 2nd if statement inside my initial if statement -
if %dist_solve%==1 (%ans_path% -b -dis -np %num_proc% -j %job% -run %run% -i therm.inp -o trun.out) else (%ans_path% -b -dis -np %num_proc% -f -m 30000 -db 5000 -j %job% -run %run% -i therm.inp -o trun.out)
tells ansys to produce data in trun.out file and powershell window logs the file real-time as ansys runs.

@Bill_Stewart I did change all the variables to match with powershell. But now, powershell does not open Ansys for same command I used for cmd to open and execute ansys input output file (%ans_path% -b -dis -np %num_proc% -j %job% -run %run% -i therm.inp -o trun.out)
I could not find any help online to run ansys using powershell. The only solution I could find was how to run ansys using cmd!

I know they are variables, (I even told you so), but without the code which precedes what you have posted, the snippet you submitted is not usable and all attempts at solving an issue would be guesses only. If you really do need help, you'd stop messing around and trying to hide information which we need to properly assist you. Please revisit my previous comment, and the link within it, then use the [Edit] facility to make the required improvements.

You've missed the point I was trying to make. Instead of trying to mix cmd.exe shell script code with PowerShell code, why not just write the whole script in PowerShell?

@Bill_Stewart Thanks for the suggestion. I was struggling with starting Ansys using powershell as the command for CMD for starting Ansys wasn't working for powershell. Fortunately, I found the solution after some troubleshooting.
Thanks for all the help :)

"the command for CMD for starting Ansys wasn't working for powershell" - We could have helped with that question, and then you wouldn't have had to mess with cmd.exe at all.

if "%therm%"=="y" (
    del /f trun.out
    fsutil file createnew trun.out 8192
    start /wait powershell -noninteractive -File "trun_tail_powershell.ps1"
    if "%dist_solve%"=="1" (
        "%ans_path%" -b -dis -np "%num_proc%" -j "%job%" -run "%run%" -i therm.inp -o trun.out
    ) else (
        "%ans_path%" -b -dis -np "%num_proc%" -f -m 30000 -db 5000 -j "%job%" -run "%run%" -i therm.inp -o trun.out
    )
    REM END 
)
dir


Compo is right, CALL shouldn't be in your script. it should be used when you want to call another batch file from within your script.

I think the issue is the start command, you want to use the start/wait command instead. The start command opens a new cmd prompt window without waiting for the window to close but with start/wait, the new window closes before the next command executes

Also i noticed inside your else clause, you have $job instead of %job%.


Hopefully, this helps.
To  modify the code to running ansys through cmd with the following code as discussed in the comment. %ans_path% -b -dis -np %num_proc% -j %job% -run %run% -i therm.inp -o trun.out. try this
if "%therm%"=="y" (
    del /f trun.out
    fsutil file createnew trun.out 8192
    start powershell -noninteractive -File "trun_tail_powershell.ps1"
    if "%dist_solve%"=="1" (
        cmd /c "%ans_path% -b -dis -np %num_proc% -j %job% -run %run% -i therm.inp -o trun.out"
    ) else (
        cmd /c "%ans_path% -b -dis -np %num_proc% -f -m 30000 -db 5000 -j %job% -run %run% -i therm.inp -o trun.out"
    )
    REM END 
)
dir


Unfoirtunately the "start/wait" did not work. It opens a blank powershell window and does not do anything else.  Which means it does not enter the 2nd if statement inside my initial if statement
"if "%dist_solve%"=="1" (
"%ans_path%" -b -dis -np "%num_proc%" -j "%job%" -run "%run%" -i therm.inp -o trun.out
)"
which produces the data file in trun.out for logging.
Thank you so much for taking the time and answering.
I did remove the CALL and also fixed the $ sign.

@User646972
switch out this line start /wait powershell -noninteractive -File "trun_tail_powershell.ps1" for this
powershell.exe -NoExit -File "trun_tail_powershell.ps1"
Try if this works, i'll update my answer if it does

I tried this also, but it tries to open powershell in same window (not preferred) and freezes!
I personally would love to use powershell to do everything.
The only problem is I can't figure out how to run ansys using powershell
The only command I found (which also works) is running ansys through cmd with the following code.
%ans_path% -b -dis -np %num_proc% -j %job% -run %run% -i therm.inp -o trun.out
when I try to use same code in powershell it says it does not recognize the code.

@User646972 if you want to figure out how to run ansys through cmd. you should update your question with that. I will update my answer for running ansys through cmd with the code you provided

what's posted in your 2nd answer should work as expected start powershell -noninteractive -File "trun_tail_powershell.ps1"  This will open a new powershell window and run the ps1 script which presumably continuously tails some log file.  With the usage of the start command, control will be returned back to cmd and continue with the rest of the batch.  Probably -noninteractive switch is unnecessary but okay to have.

I had some reasoning behind using both CMD and Powershell. However, later realized that everything can be done through powershell. So I switched to powershell for all the commands and data logging. I was able to figure out most of the problems. Thank you so much for your time and help :)
